# Network, moving large folder : Photo Library

Tags: network, data-transfer, photo-stream, photos.app, afp

I want to move my Photo Library through my Synology NAS,
I know I'm gonna lose the iCloud Syncing (which is very annoying...) but anyway.

Every time I trying to move the Photo Library (quite heavy, 125.85 GB I have this error "The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -50)."

I've tried with SMB, AFP, and I'm not trying with a basic terminal command 
which probably gonna failed too.

```
sudo mv /Users/Kevin/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary  /Volumes/photo/
```

All this is connected through an Asus RT-68U, which is suppose to be fast, but ... you know..

I only have 11 devices connected on the network at this time, most are in idle.

[image: Connected devices]

Ethernet are quite ok, and wifi is may be a bit high : 
[image: Ethernet]

[image: Wifi]

Edit:
When exporting photo through the Photos.app export :
[image: Export]

[image: NAS Network Settings]

Comment: Also, Just thinking, should I not jut export the photo from the photo.app file menu otherwise the pictures will be only available through the photo.app

Comment: Does Console.app or the synology's log give you any other information?

Comment: I didnt check the log, but terminal failed "mv: /Volumes/photo/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/2015/04/25/20150425-083443/IMG_2638.MOV: Invalid argument
" 
 would the name be too long ? 
Also, don't get it but file on NAS is now 128.37 GB when original folder is 125.85 GB, no sense.

Comment: Update, as per the Synology log, its seems that even if only moving the file per AFP, its converting the files : "2016-01-20
14:17:22
Error
DiskStation
user
System
System failed to convert video [/volume2/photo/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/2014/06/07/20140607-131519/IMG_2183.MP4] to mp..." so that probably why

Comment: Kevin—the files would be much more accessible if exported. The .photoslibrary "file" is actually a special folder. That the size is different on the NAS is likely due to the use of a different file system. I'm not familiar with the inner workings of Synology, but I did notice that you are referencing two different files in the two log entries. Can you find a log entry on each device that deals with the same file?

Comment: hi @samh, I expected to be the file system too, I actually forgot the idea to move the folder, instead I'm exporting from the photos.app, but this is failing too : http://i.stack.imgur.com/GHdEN.png maybe I should just change the network settings of my NAS   http://i.stack.imgur.com/bHx6j.png